# What to add to a Linux embedded env to have .cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so files supported

Tags: python, buildroot, toolchain

I'm trying to generate a functional Linux embedded system through Buildroot. I added some customized libraries for a python application. However, it seems like my system doesn't support `.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` files that are present in my libraries. I don't know if it can actually work like this but is there some module or alike that I could add to my toolchain so that this extension of file is supported ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your python libraries as a buildroot package, so they are cross-compiled. See [the buildroot manual on python packages](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#_infrastructure_for_python_packages).